# Set value of a checkbox to "checked" when appending to another part of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

when a checkbox on my page is clicked, I grab it's containing elements and append the whole block to another part of the page. Like this:

```
  $('.favourite [type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var check = $(this),
            checked = $(check).attr("checked"),
            id = $(check).attr("id").split("-")[1],
            parent = $("#food-" + id),
            parentContent = $("<div />").append($("#food-" + id).clone()).html(),
            favelist = $(".favourites .content");

        if (checked === "checked") {
            $(favelist).append(parentContent);
        }
    });
```

I want the new checkbox to be checked when it is pasted into the favelist. Is there anything I can do to parentContent- which contains the HTML block of the checkbox & surrounding elements- so that it is already checked when it is appended?

Comment: not answering ur question, just a heads up ... you should use `click` instead of `change` for the event. older versions of webkit did not recognize the `change` event on checkboxes and radiobuttons.

Comment: Other thing is that you should use `prop` instead of `attr` if you go for id or checked.

Comment: @KamilT - or just `this.checked`.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea right, and I think that `this.id` instead of `$(this).prop('id')` would work too.

Comment: alright back to the question ... where is the "new checkbox" in your code?

Comment: The "new checkbox" is in .favourites .content (see favelist = $(".favourites .content");, $(favelist).append(parentContent);)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to append a string to favelist, you can append a jQuery element right away. By doing this, all properties and styling set through the DOM will be kept, such as `checked`.

That means you can drop both `$("<div />").append(` and `).html()`.

The resulting code would be the following.

```
   $('.favourite [type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var check = $(this),
            checked = $(check).attr("checked"),
            id = $(check).attr("id").split("-")[1],
            parent = $("#food-" + id),
            parentContent = $("#food-" + id).clone(),
            favelist = $(".favourites .content");

        if (checked === "checked") {
            $(favelist).append(parentContent);
        }
    });
```

It will be faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
checked = this.checked,
```

**Or**

```
checked = $(check).prop("checked"),
```

in place of

```
checked = $(check).attr("checked"),
```

And **Codition** like,

```
if (checked === true) {
     $(favelist).append(parentContent);
}
```

**Full code,**

```
$('.favourite [type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    var check = $(this),
        checked = this.checked,
        id = $(check).attr("id").split("-")[1],
        parent = $("#food-" + id),
        parentContent = $("<div />").append($("#food-" + id).clone()).html(),
        favelist = $(".favourites .content");

    if (checked === true) {
        $(favelist).append(parentContent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give this the old college try ...

```
$('.favourite').on('click','[type="checkbox"]',function(){
    var chk = this.checked,
        id = this.id.split("-")[1],
        parent = $("#food-" + id),
        parentContent = $("<div />").append($("#food-" + id).clone()).html(),
        $favelist = $(this).find(".content");

    if (chk === "checked") {
        $favelist.append(parentContent).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked');
    }
});
```

This adds a little delegation action, as well as uses the vanilla JS versions of `checked` and `id` for performance purposes. It also eliminates the double-wrapping you were doing with `favelist`.